# Validating XML fragment against complexType in schema in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xsd-validation

I have an XML fragment that I would like to test against a complexType in a schema. The problem is the schema is hugely complex and the fragment I would like to test relates specifically to a single complex type. Is there a way to validate the element against the schema without having to wrap it in a massive mocked-up document that validates against the whole schema?

Answer (score 0):

Since Schema is XML too, you could try [DOM](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to extract the parts of the Schema that would validate the complex type. Then [load the fragment into a DOMDocument](http://de.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php) and use [DOMDocument::schemaValidateSource](http://de.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.schemavalidatesource.php).